# GGally - unexpected behavior with ggpairs(..., diag = list( continuous = 'density'))

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggally

I am trying to generate a scatterplot matrix with density plots in the diagonals (using ggplot, preferably). The documentation for `ggpairs` in the GGally package states:

> diag is a list that may only contain the variables 'continuous' and
>   'discrete'. Each element of the diag list is a string implementing the
>   following options: continuous = exactly one of ('density', 'bar',
>   'blank'); discrete = exactly one of ('bar', 'blank').

which suggests(??) that this should be possible using `diag=list(continuous="density")`.

But the following code:

```
xx <- mtcars[,c(1,3,4,6)]   ## extract mpg, disp, hp, and wt from mtcars
library(GGally)
ggpairs(xx,diag=list(continuous="density"))
```

gives this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

NB: Trying to do the same thing with `plotmatrix(xx)` gives this:

[image]

which fails because the density plots are, evidently, scaled in each diagonal facet using the range based on the full dataset (`xx`), rather than the range based on `xx` subsetted for the appropriate facet. As a result, the second row (disp) looks good because disp has the greatest range, but rows 1 and 4 are crunched.

Comment: @rcs - Re: your edits. The snippet on diag from ggpairs was cut and pasted directly from the documentation (where implementation is spelled incorrectly). Your edit makes it appear that this is not so. BTW: do you have an answer for the question??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So I finally figured this out, by studying a different question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20372224/). It turns out that unless `axisLabels` is set to `"show"`, density plots on the diagonal are suppressed, without warning.

```
xx <- mtcars[,c(1,3,4,6)]   ## extract mpg, disp, hp, and wt from mtcars
library(GGally)
ggpairs(xx, diag=list(continuous="density"), axisLabels='show')
```

Produces this, as expected:
[image]